# Switching from login to tabbased view without stacking both views on application launch

Tags: iphone, iphone-developer-program

I have currently stacked both the login and tabbased view on `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.. how when i use this iphone runs `viewDidLoad` method in both the clasess. Please help me with a way to add one view at once.. First the login after successful login switch to tab based view.

Comment: post some code of applicationDidFinishLaunchingwithOptions method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let tab based view be your rootViewController, but only if you need a login (in case you save login), present login view as modal view controller

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is show your `loginViewController` in your `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and then when the user has logged in you can use the code below to set your `tabViewController` as the `rootViewController` of the window.  This will remove the `loginViewController` and replace it with your `tabViewController`.

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
appDelegate.window.rootViewController = tabViewController
```